# Problem with Java generic interface

Tags: java, generics

Is `People` in the following Java snippet a *type* name (like `T` or `K`) or a concrete *class* (or *interface*) name?

```
public class Student implements Comparable<People> { ... }
```

And where can I find explanation or specification on such issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this context, `People` is the name of a concrete class, not a type variable.  If you wanted it to be a type variable, you'd have to say that `Student` itself is a generic:

```
public class Student<People> implements Comparable<People> { ... }
```

By the way, notationally, wildcards like `T` and `K` that are stand-ins for classes are usually called *type variables* rather than *types*.